# Has anyone found a way to supress a false positive warning in APEX code for PMD?

Tags: apex, pmd

When looking at PMD documentation it appears that for apex code there is no way to do a suppression for a single line of code. I have a lot of false positives that have been making builds fail so I need to find away around this besides for suppressing the rule for the whole class. Has anyone found a way around this for APEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMD has 3 ways to suppress warnings in Apex:

1. Using [`@SuppressWarnings`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#annotations), which works on any element that is annotateable (classes, fields, methods, etc.)
2. Using [`violationSuppressRegex`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#violation-suppress-regex)
3. Using [`violationSuppressXPath`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#violation-suppress-xpath)

See also: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#annotations

**Update:**

As of PMD 6.22.0, usage of `// NOPMD` comments is also a possibility.